# How to Start a foreground service on Device Restart On Oreo(API 26+)

Tags: android, service

I am starting a service in the foreground to track user location when the app goes into background or killed state. But when device shutdown then service is killed by Android OS.
To start the foreground service I have registered the Receiver BOOT_COMPLETED in Manifest & trying to start the service from the receiver but on Oreo & above
I can't start the service when the app is in the background or in kill state.

Comment: on which phone(model) you are trying to do this

Comment: In all Android Running Devices